# How to convert minutes to hours using MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

Personal I have this query that is returning the time in minutes for me. But I want this query to return in hours and minutes rather than in minutes. It's already tried using  [FLOOR() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html), but to no avail.

**SQL**

```
SELECT
   vencido.tickets_id,
   Tickets.name,
   Tickets.due_date,
   Tickets.solvedate,
   Cat.completename,
   TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour, Tickets.date, Tickets.solvedate) as Tempo 
FROM
   glpi_vencidos as vencido 
   INNER JOIN
      glpi_tickets as Tickets 
      ON (Tickets.id = vencido.tickets_id) 
   INNER JOIN
      glpi_itilcategories as Cat 
      ON (Tickets.itilcategories_id = Cat.id) 
WHERE
   Tickets.solvedate between STR_TO_DATE('01/06/2017', '%d/%m/%Y') and STR_TO_DATE('01/07/2017', '%d/%m/%Y') 
   and vencido.situacao = 1
```

**My result in minutes**

[image: My result]

Answer (score 3):

You need `DIV` and `%` operators.

`DIV` is the integer division and `%` is the modulo function, returning the reminder:

```
SELECT 12345 DIV 60 AS hrs, 12345 % 60 as min;
```

**UPDATE**

You have to change your query such way:

```
SELECT
   . . . . .
   TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, Tickets.date, Tickets.solvedate) DIV 60 AS TempoH,    
   TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, Tickets.date, Tickets.solvedate) % 60 AS TempoM
   . . . . .
```

Comment: What would the implementation look like in my original code?

Comment: Can you post your query that returns the time in minutes?

Comment: This is my question, but I can pass you here as well.. Https://gist.github.com/Nerato/d5b46ee72981f5e9bd32f60bfed8412b

Comment: I'll test here and tell you the result! Do you think my query can be improved?

Comment: `JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` are completely equivalent in the `mysql` so you can replace `INNER JOIN` by plain `JOIN`.